# Find friends active (logged in) on Facebook app right now

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I know /me/friends will give list of friends who use a particular fb app

This is what I want to do:

if A, B, C are 3 facebook friends using an fb app, all three logged into the app currently, then all the 3 will be visible to each other

If A logged out of the fb app only B and C will be visible to each other

Basically I want to show list of friends currently (real-time) using my facebook app...

Please let me know if it possible and how

Thanks in advance

Comment: Store when the user start using the app as logged in. And when they stop using the app mark the user as logged out

Comment: @WizKid, Thanks... can you please elaborate ... like should I store the user id's .. is there any code/example available

Comment: what is a primary key for a particular fb user? the fb id? but I read it can change with time

Comment: where did you read that it can change with time?

Comment: about your question: you have to program the activity monitor on your own, there is no api for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have said, just log in your own database when a user logs into your application.  Store the Facebook ID and the timestamp of their login and then you can update that timestamp any time a user completes an action or you run a script.  This way the timestamp in your database remains up to date.

You can then compare this with the user's friend's timestamps.  It wouldn't be exactly real time (though it would be very close), but then only show the users as online if they have been active within a certain window of time (like 30 seconds, 1 minute, 5 minutes, etc).